# extract text plugin - Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found:

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I'm using the following module in my webpack config -

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: "style-loader",
    use: [
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: "[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]"
        }
      },
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

I'm getting an error `Uncaught Error: Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'shared/variables`

It looks like my css can't import files. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using webpack 3.5.5 and extract text plugin 3.0.0

Comment: 6 years in stackoverflow... I would expect that you know how to use the code-block syntax in your question :(

Comment: @Dekel I'd expect stackoverflow to supprt markdown like everyone else

Comment: Well... until they do - use what you have. it really isn't hard to select the relevant code and click on the `{}` button.

Comment: fixed it. Any input on the question? I imagine you're an absolute joy in PR reviews.

Comment: It looks like webpack is looking for some module that doesn't exist. Did you `npm install`? Do you have all the relevant modules in the `package.json` file?

Comment: @Dekel I think you're right, I'd forgotten to configure webpack to accept css files. Thanks! Post an answer and I'll click accept.